# Conditional Summing R | How to sum rows and by a conditional rule

Tags: r

I am looking to sum a row with 4 variables horizontally to become 1 column. Also, there are NA values in some of the data, where I am looking to do the following:

(If there is NAs)

```
(sum the row have values) * 4/(4 - number of NAs)

Example    [1]   [2]   [3]   [4]  [Row sum]
            2     3     1     5    => sum = 11
            5     2     3     NA   => sum = 10 + (4/4-1)
            .     .     .     .    =>
            .     .     .     .    =>
            .     .     .     .    =>
           etc   etc   etc   etc
```

I am looking for a function that can sum these rows in one function and curious to know how this would be done.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `tidyverse` approach:

```
require(tidyverse)
#Sample data
set.seed(123) 
df <- data.frame(v1 = sample(c(1:10, NA), 10),
                 v2 = sample(c(1:10, NA), 10),
                 v3 = sample(c(1:10, NA), 10),
                 v4 = sample(c(1:10, NA), 10))

df %>% 
  mutate(mySum = rowSums(data.frame(v1, v2, v3, v4), na.rm = TRUE) * 
           (4 / (4 - rowSums(is.na(data.frame(v1, v2, v3, v4))))))
```

output:

```
   v1 v2 v3 v4    mySum
1   4 NA 10 NA 28.00000
2   8  5  7 10 30.00000
3  NA  7  6  7 26.66667
4  10 10  8  9 37.00000
5   7  1  5  1 14.00000
6   1  6 NA  3 13.33333
7   3  2  3  4 12.00000
8   9  9  9  8 35.00000
9   2  4  1  5 12.00000
10  6  8  4  6 24.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this -

```
row_sums <- function(df) {
  rowSums(df, na.rm = T) + is.na(rowSums(df))*ncol(df)/(ncol(df) - rowSums(is.na(df)))
}

df <- data.frame(v1 = c(2,5), v2 = c(3,2), v3 = c(1,3), v4 = c(5,NA))

df$v5 <- row_sums(df)
df

# v1 v2 v3 v4       v5
# 1  2  3  1  5 11.00000
# 2  5  2  3 NA 11.33333
```